# Magento - Change the quote_id after login

Tags: magento, magento-1.9, observers

I'm adding products to my cart while I'm not logged in. My `quote_id is 597`.

In the checkout process I'm logging in (in the first step) and I've noticed that my quote has changed.

`quote_id 597` has disappeared from database and the new `quote_id is now 555`.

What's the observer,class and method that are in charge of this quote change, as I have a temporary table in the database where I also need to modify that `quote_id`?

Answer (score 1):

on checkout login there is an observer that performs Quote Merge, 
that is if the customer is having nay quotes in database that will merge with the current one ,

if you do not want to merge the quotes you can set your own observer to remove all previous items,

config file

```
<global>
    <events>
        <sales_quote_merge_before>
            <observers>
                <mymage_clearoldcartproducts_observer>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>MyMage_Clearoldcartproducts_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>removeCustomerQuote</method>
                </mymage_clearoldcartproducts_observer>
            </observers>
        </sales_quote_merge_before>
    </events>
</global>
```

Observer.php file

```
<?php

class MyMage_Clearoldcartproducts_Model_Observer extends Mage_Checkout_Model_Session {
    public function removeCustomerQuote() {
        $customerQuote = Mage::getModel('sales/quote')
                ->setStoreId(Mage::app()->getStore()->getId())
                ->loadByCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId());

        if ($customerQuote->getId() && $this->getQuoteId() != $customerQuote->getId()) {
            // Removing old cart items of the customer.
            foreach ($customerQuote->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $item->isDeleted(true);
                if ($item->getHasChildren()) {
                    foreach ($item->getChildren() as $child) {
                        $child->isDeleted(true);
                    }
                }
            }
            $customerQuote->collectTotals()->save();
        } else {

            $this->getQuote()->getBillingAddress();
            $this->getQuote()->getShippingAddress();
            $this->getQuote()->setCustomer(Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomer())
                    ->setTotalsCollectedFlag(false)
                    ->collectTotals()
                    ->save();
        }
        return $this;
    }

}
?>
```